# Android Google Map. Заменить иконку своего местоположения.

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты, icon

Как можно заменить синюю иконку с радаром заменить на оранжевую.

На скрине ниже показаны две иконки, одна моя, которую я прикручиваю по указанной своей геолокации, но мне этого мало, хочется как-то красиво заменить. Не подскажите, как это можно сделать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

хмм.... 
может поможет внимательно почитать про маркеры:
а можно просто скопировать :-)

```
var _Marker = 'http://..................*.png';
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: myMap,
  position: latlng,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
  title:'I'
  icon: _Marker});
```